# Uploading photographs using MEAN.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, ng-file-upload

I’m using [this tutorial](https://github.com/Hitman666/MEAN_MVC_4thTutorial), which is based on the MEAN stack.
I want to store photographs that users can upload with MongoDB on a server.

**included: [Angular directive to upload files](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)**

**create-spot.client.view.html**

```
<div data-ng-controller="SpotsCreateController">
    <form class="form-signin" data-ng-submit="create(picFile)" novalidate>
        <label>Upload an image</label>
        <input type="file" id="articleimage" ng-model="picFile" ng-file-select="" ng-file-change="generateThumb(picFile[0], $files)" multiple name="file" accept="image/*">
        <img ng-show="picFile[0].dataUrl != null" ng-src="{{picFile[0].dataUrl}}" class="img-thumbnail" height="50" width="100">
        <span class="progress" ng-show="picFile[0].progress >= 0">      
            <div style="width:{{picFile[0].progress}}%" ng-bind="picFile[0].progress + '%'" class="ng-binding"></div>
        </span> 
        <span ng-show="picFile[0].result">Upload Successful</span>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">

        <div data-ng-show="error">
            <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**view-spot.client.view.html**

```
<div data-ng-controller="SpotsViewController">
    <section data-ng-init="findOne()">
        <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{spot.image}}" id="image-id" width="200" height="200"/>
    </section>
</div>
```

**application.js**

```
var app = angular.module('newApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch', 'ui.bootstrap', 'users', 'spots']);
```

**spots.create.client.controller.js**

```
angular.module('spots').controller('SpotsCreateController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'Authentication', 'Spots', '$location'
function($scope, $timeout, Authentication, Spots, $location) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader !== null;

    $scope.create = function(picFile) {
        var spot = new Spots({
            title: this.title,
            description: this.description,
            image: null
        });
        spot.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('spots/' + response._id);
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };

    $scope.doTimeout = function(file) {
        $timeout( function() {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    file.dataUrl = e.target.result;
                });
            };
        });
    };
    $scope.generateThumb = function(file) {
        if (file) {
            if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
                $scope.doTimeout(file);
            }
        }
    };
```

**spot.server.model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SpotSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: false
    }
});

mongoose.model('Spot', SpotSchema);
```

**spots.server.routes.js**

```
var multiparty = require('connect-multiparty'),
    multipartyMiddleware = multiparty();

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.route('/api/spots')
        .get(spots.list)
        .post(users.requiresLogin, multipartyMiddleware, spots.create);

    app.route('/api/spots/:spotId')
        .get(spots.read)
        .put(users.requiresLogin, spots.hasAuthorization, spots.update)
        .delete(users.requiresLogin, spots.hasAuthorization, spots.delete);

    app.param('spotId', spots.spotByID);
};
```

**spots.server.controller.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    Spot = mongoose.model('Spot');

exports.create = function(req, res) {
    if (req.files.file) {
        var file = req.files.file;
    }

    var spot = new Spot(req.body);
    spot.creator = req.user;

    fs.readFile(file.path, function (err,original_data) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        var base64Image = original_data.toString('base64');
        fs.unlink(file.path, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('failed to delete ' + file.path);
            } else {
                console.log('successfully deleted ' + file.path);
            }
        });
        spot.image = base64Image;
        spot.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.json(spot);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

What did I do wrong? Please consider that I want to limit the file sizes, and I thought using `base64` is good start. The issue is that the photograph is not stored in the database because the controller doesn’t work with the rest.

Comment: What the issue is exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is the problem you are experiencing, and at what step is it going wrong?

For Express backend apps I usually use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) middleware for handling file uploads. Also, I create separate routes/controllers for dealing with the files rather than trying to process them at the same time I'm saving the parent object. This allows me to separate the logic nicely and not worry about the parent object not being saved when the file upload fails. You could use the JS API for ng-file-upload to handle that in Angular.

Example routes in Express (we have a "club" with a "logo" image here):

```
router.post(
  '/logo',
  ensureAuthenticated, ensureAdmin,
  logoCtrl.upload,
  logoCtrl.save
);
router.get(
  '/:clubId/logo.*',
  logoCtrl.stream
);
```

Example controller methods:

```
let multer = require('multer');
module.exports = {

  /**
   * Upload logo
   */
  save(req, res, next) {

    //Get club and file
    let club = req.user.club;
    let file = req.file;

    //Update
    club.logo = {
      data: file.buffer,
      mimeType: file.mimetype
    };

    //Save
    club.save()
      .then(() => {
        res.end();
      })
      .catch(next);
  },

  /**
   * Stream logo
   */
  stream(req, res, next) {
    let club = req.club;
    res.contentType(club.logo.mimeType);
    res.send(club.logo.data);
  },

  /**
   * Upload middleware
   */
  upload(req, res, next) {

    //Create upload middleware
    let upload = multer({
      storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
      limits: {
        fileSize: 50000000
      }
    }).single('logo');

    //Use middleware
    upload(req, res, next);
  }
};
```

So as you can see, it's quite simple with multer and all you really need is one route for uploading the logo, with two controller methods, one to register the multer middleware and process the file, and the other to save it to the MongoDB (in this case attached to the club in the request).

Just make sure that ng-file-upload uses the same field name for uploading the file as multer is expecting. In the above example that's "logo". If you're unsure, check in the request what your client app is sending to the server and make sure the server app is expecting the same field name.

Let me know if you have further trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `formidable` and `gridfs-stream`

```
//controller
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  Spot = mongoose.model('Spot');

exports.create = function(req, res) {
  handleRequest(req, function(err, spot) {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    }

    res.json(spot);

  });
};

function handleRequest(req) {

  var spot = new Spot(req.body);
  spot.creator = req.user;

  var formidable = require('formidable');

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    var file = files.qqfile;
    if (file && file.name && file.name.trim !== '') {
      if (file.size > 5000000) {
        message = 'file is too large';
      }
      if (!file.type) {
        message = 'file is not an image';
      }
      if (file.type.indexOf('image/') !== 0) {
        message = 'file is not an image type';
      }
    }
    if (message) {
      logger.info('Uploading failed', file, message);
      return done(message);
    }

    uploadFile(mongoose.connection, 'Pictures', files.qqfile, require('uuid').v1(), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!data) return done(false, null);

      if (typeof data === 'string') {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
      }
      logger.info('[PHOTOS]', 'Uploaded', data.filename);
      photo = {
        unique_id: token,
        name: file.name,
        contentType: file.type
      };

      spot.photos = spot.photos || [];
      spot.photos.push(photo);
      spot.markModified('photos');
      spot.save(done);

    });
  });
}

function uploadFile(DB, className, data, token, callback) {
  var grid = require('gridfs-stream');
  var gfs = grid(DB.db, mongoose.mongo);

  var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename: token,
    root: className
  });
  writestream.on('close', function (file) {
    return callback(null, file);
  });

  if (data.path) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    if (!fs.existsSync(data.path)) {
      return callback(false);
    }
    var pipe = false;
    if (data.pipe) {
      pipe = data.pipe;
    } else {
      var fs = require('fs');
      if (!fs.existsSync(data.path)) {
        return callback(false);
      }
      var rs = fs.createReadStream(data.path);
      pipe = rs.pipe.bind(rs);
    }
    return pipe(writestream);
  } else {
    logger.error('[PHOTO] no path', data);
  }
  callback(false);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I’m a little bit lost because I do not know how to include it do my files, as your solution is something completely different (different modules, ...)

Comment: Very nice of you! :) The other files really don’t need adjustments?

Comment: Run it in Chrome and check what your Network Tab shows...
You should see something like `Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryTBxXOJDciMbRAhmD` in the headers and `------WebKitFormBoundaryTBxXOJDciMbRAhmD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfile"; filename="somefile.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif` in the payload...

Comment: When I click on the button nothing happens, and Chrome tells me that the status is pending. Then, I get an error in my console `Reference Error: generateFilename is not defined`.

Comment: ah yes, you must include a function to generate a unique filename...
try `require('uuid').v1()` instead

Comment: Sorry but: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined || if (data.path) {`. I’m not allowed to chat because I do not have enough reputations

Comment: console.log is your friend... This is code I extracted from our app, I cannot debug it anymore...